# Non-orientable closed 4- or 3-manifolds with known cohomology ring

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, cohomology

Are there any examples of non-orientable closed 4-(or 3-)manifolds $M$ whose cohomology ring $H^*(M,\mathbb{Z}_n)$ and/or $H^*(M,\mathbb{Z})$ are known.

Here we assume that $M$ is not a product of lower dimensional manifolds, and is not a connected sum.

The following paper give a class of examples for 3-manifold based on torus bundle: https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.0518 . I wonder if there are examples for 4-manifolds and other examples for 3-manifolds.

This question is motivated from a physics problem. Manifolds with known cohomology ring are like probes that can detect topological orders in quantum matter. We like to have as much probes as possible in order to distinguish all topological orders.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}P^4$?

Comment: Yes $\mathbb{R}P^4$ is certainly the simplest example. I am not so clear in my question. I am looking for a sequence of examples, with different torsions in $H^*(M,\mathbb{Z})$.  $\mathbb{R}P^4$ has only 2-torsion. Are there examples with other torsion? Also I wonder if cohomology ring $H^*(\mathbb{R}P^4; \mathbb{Z}_n)$ is known?

Comment: @Xiao-GangWen it should be possible to compute $H^*(\mathbb{RP}^4, \mathbb{Z}/n)$ in the same way as for $\mathbb Z$ coefficients, which [Hatcher's book](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf) discusses following Thm. 3.19 (pp. 220-22).

Comment: As for torsion in $\mathbb Z$ coefficients, lens spaces (Hatcher, Exm. 2.43, p. 144) are a simple example, though they're orientable.

Answer (score 2):

The Grassmannian of unoriented 2-planes in $\mathbb{R}^4$ is 4-dimensional. A product of an unorientable surface and an orientable one is 4-dimensional.

Comment: The cohomology is computed, for example, in McCleary's *A User's Guide to Spectral Sequences*.

Comment: Here, we are looking for examples which are not a product of lower dimensional manifolds, and is not a connected sum.

Comment: Is the Grassmannian of unoriented 2-planes $\mathbb{R} P^4$?

Comment: No.  For computations of the cohomology rings of oriented and unoriented real Grassmannians, see for instance http://arxiv.org/abs/1610.07968.

Comment: Why isn't this Grassmannian orientable?

Comment: The unoriented grassmannian of 2-planes in $\mathbb{R}^4$ is orientable. In general, $\operatorname{Gr}(m, n)$ is orientable if and only if $m$ is even.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: right, oops. Thanks for pointing that out.